# Add value of HTML tr into DataTable

Tags: c#, html, database

I have a Structure of a table in HTML like this:

```
tbody

     tr
         td
         td
         td
    </tr>
    tr
         td
         td
         td
    </tr>
```

Now I want to add a the first tr in the first row of datatable, the second   in the second one.

The first row will 3 cell that is the value of 3

```
<td></td>
```

Please help me. Many Thanks.

Comment: Do you think you can explain this a little better with better formatting?  Also go into more detail, e.g. why did you tag this with html-agility-pack.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do a little separation here. HTML is intended to help you establish what the viewing space will look like in your browser. It reads like you want to dynamically create a table based on data coming from somewhere else. If we assume, for a moment, that the data is being delivered to the browser as an array (raw, XML, JSON), then you would need some JavaScript code in your browser page to receive that array and then dynamically build the table. This approach will run faster over the network, but load the user's PC a little more.
 You can also do all of this on the server; you've tagged this question with C#, so on your Windows server, you could dynamically build the table by creating the html tags and putting the appropriate values from your database into the generated HTML stream that you send to the browser. This approach will place more load on the network and slightly less on the user's PC. 
 We can help you more if you can provide more information about where the data resides and how you are planning on sending it to the browser.